# How to express the following equation containing sigma and factorial notation in Python (SymPy)?

Tags: python, sympy, factorial

Mclaurin Series for exponential function:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2CWp.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help on how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

This is how you write it:

```
from sympy import *
x, n = symbols("x n")
expr = Sum(x**n / factorial(n), (n, 0, oo))
print(expr)
# out: Sum(x**n/factorial(n), (n, 0, oo))
```

You can execute `help(Sum)` to read its documentation.